# Utilizing a character vector inside a function

Tags: r, function

I have the following function:

```
SubsetObject <- function(data)
{
  data <- read.table(data)
  data <- subset(data, action!="synchronize")
  # data <- subset(data, action!="assigned")
  # data <- subset(data, action!="subscribed")
  # data <- subset(data, action!="unsubscribed")
  # data <- subset(data, action!="merged")
  # data <- subset(data, action!="mentioned")
  data <- subset(data, action!="referenced")
  # data <- subset(data, action!="head_ref_cleaned")
  # data <- subset(data, action!="head_ref_deleted")
  # data <- subset(data, action!="head_ref_restored")
 (data)
}
```

Currently, it's using a very awkward manual approach to subsetting - I simply comment out the `action` character strings that I want to keep. Instead, I would like to be able to pass a character vector to the function, like so:

```
SubsetObject(data, exclude = c("synchronize", "referenced"))
```

And then do the subsetting so that those character strings are excluded form the `action` variable. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably just use `%in%`:

```
data <- subset(data,!action %in% c("synchronize", "referenced"))
```